# Possible to use bind :variable inside SELECT clause?

Tags: apex, soql, query, dynamic-soql

I cannot use the `String[] ss` inside the `SELECT` statement. It is giving me errors:

> unexpected token: ':'

**Code**

```
public void getSubscribers(Id listId){
    String[] ss = new String[]{'Id', 'Name'};
    Map<String, String> fields = DopplerListCriteriasUtil.getAvailableLookupObjects();
    for (String e: fields.keySet()) {
            ss.add(e);
    }
    Map<Id, DopplerListSubscriber__c> suscMap = new Map<Id, DopplerListSubscriber__c>([
        SELECT :ss DopplerList__c FROM DopplerListSubscriber__c WHERE DopplerList__c = :listId
    ]);
    String concatSql = null;
}
```

This statement is giving me errors on `:ss`

```
Map<Id, DopplerListSubscriber__c> suscMap = new Map<Id, DopplerListSubscriber__c>([
    SELECT :ss DopplerList__c FROM DopplerListSubscriber__c WHERE DopplerList__c = :listId
]);
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to use a dynamic query for that:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Here's an example from the article to show a bit about how it works:

```
String myTestString = 'TestName';
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
```

Basically, you'll just update it to look more like this:

```
String myTestString = 'TestName';
List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query('SELECT Id, ' + ss + ' FROM MyCustomObject__c WHERE Name = :myTestString');
```

Comment: Hello mate, I saw that example, but its not so clean, specially when I use a map, I though there was another option.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use dynamic SOQL if you want to add fields dynamically. Merge syntax is not supported.

```
List<String> fields = new List<String> { 'Id', 'Name' };
String soql = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ',') + ' FROM MyObject__c WHERE ...';
List<MyObject__c> records = Database.query(soql);
```

I actually often have dynamic filters as well when I'm in such a scenario, and might use a similar strategy there. Another basic example:

```
List<String> fields = new List<String> { 'Id', 'Name' };
List<String> filters = new List<String> { 'CreatedDate = TODAY', '...' };

String soql = String.format('SELECT {0} FROM MyObject__c WHERE {1}', new List<String> {
    String.join(fields, ', '), String.join(filters, ' AND ')
});
List<MyObject__c> records = Database.query(soql);
```

Comment: nice implementation tips

Comment: I could have follow this approach

Answer (score 5):

Salesforce does not support variable binding in the `SELECT` clause.

From **[Using Apex Variables in SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_variables.htm)**:

> SOQL and SOSL statements in Apex can reference Apex code variables and expressions if they’re preceded by a colon (:). This use of a local code variable within a SOQL or SOSL statement is called a bind. The Apex parser first evaluates the local variable in code context before executing the SOQL or SOSL statement. Bind expressions can be used as:
>
> - The search string in FIND clauses.
> - The filter literals in WHERE clauses.
> - The value of the IN or NOT IN operator in WHERE clauses, allowing filtering on a dynamic set of values. Note that this is of particular use with a list of IDs or Strings, though it works with lists of any type.
> - The division names in WITH DIVISION clauses.
> - The numeric value in LIMIT clauses.
> - The numeric value in OFFSET clauses.
>
> Bind expressions can't be used with other clauses, such as INCLUDES.